# How can I know the in-flight Internet prices for a given flight number?

Tags: air-travel, price, internet

Internet prices vary quite a lot between different flights.  How can I know the in-flight Internet prices for a given flight number?

Comment: This will vary airline by airline. There's no central database for this, it's not in the GDS. Especially it will also vary based on status. Thus, this question is too broad.

Comment: @chx we can give a canonical answer to "how can I find out the price for any given flight", even if its something like "go on the carrier's website"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no other way but to go on the carrier's website and check. It'll likely be split into categories of something like "domestic" "international". Also, frequent flier statuses will *drastically* wary this price to the extent of the very information not being available to people below certain status. (You bet that guy who flies 500 000 miles every year with the airline ain't going to pay 9 dollars an hour for wifi! Quod licet Iovi, non licet bovi.)

Comment: Likewise for different service classes.